# Why do I need to escape parentheses in awk string constant?

Tags: awk

consider a simple file named `test` containing the following text:

```
abc(def)
```

With `awk`, if I found out that this will work:

```
awk '$0 ~ "abc\(def\)"' test
```

but it won't work if the parentheses are not properly escaped:

```
awk '$0 ~ "abc(def)"' test
```

Dropping the right parenthesis, I got this error:

```
awk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (missing ')')
abc(def
```

Isn't string quoted by `""` string constant in awk? Why are `()` treated as regular expression special character in a string constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the documentation of gawk [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_9.html#SEC91), it says (emphasis mine)

> Regexp matching and non-matching are also very common expressions. The
>   left operand of the `~` and `!~` operators is a string. **The right
>   operand is** either a constant regular expression enclosed in slashes
>   (/regexp/), or **any expression, whose string value is used as a dynamic
>   regular expression** (see section Using Dynamic Regexps).

Regexp constants are created when running the script and can not be changed during the run of the program while dynamic regular expressions can be changed by the script.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize my understanding of `~` is inexact. I should think about that.

Comment: This is one thing I learned from some answers here: You should always check the documentation, it's mostly explained there, although I didn't believe that at first.

Comment: That's right, at least theoretically. But at times it's hard to guess which part of your understanding doesn't match the truth, in which case you are somewhat blind to find the correct part of documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understood the question, then the answer is something like this:

```
awk -F ',' '{ print "(" $1, $2 ")" }'
```

You should type **(** between **" "**. Any special symbols you may print with " "